# how to store timer in localstorage and resume on page reload

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage

I have a timer on my page that starts counting from the moment the page is loaded, shows it in minutes and seconds. There is also a save button that saves this time, and when we reload the page, the timer should start counting from the time we saved. But on reboot it writes NAN: NAN. How can I save and resume timing correctly?

```
let timerInterval;
let timerStart;
let time = 0;
 
function updateTime() {
  time++;
  let mins = parseInt(time / 60);
  let secs = time % 60;
  if(mins < 10) {
    mins = '0' + String(mins);
  }
  if(secs < 10) {
    secs = '0' + String(secs);
}
document.querySelector('#timespan').innerHTML = `${mins}:${secs}`;  
} 
 
function startTimer() {
  timerInterval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
  time = 0;
  timerStart = true;
};
 
function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
  time = 0;
  timerStart = false;
}
 
document.querySelector('.save-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('currentTime', document.querySelector('#timespan').innerHTML);
}
 
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector('#timespan').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('currentTime');
}, false );
```

Comment: Could you solve your problem? Is there more info to improve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse `localStorage` content to hydrate your global `time` variable <s>before</s> after you call `startTimer` (which is not shown in the code you posted).